# Get the values of multiple datepickers in a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have got multiple jQuery datepickers in a datatable. I'm trying to get the value of each datepicker. However, I only get the value of first datepicker. How can I get the value of each in the loop ?

```
table.rows().eq(0).each(function (index) {
    var val = $('[datepicker]').val();
    var selectedDate = val;
};
```

[image]

Comment: you need to make a loop on date picker of the data table row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Since datepicker doesn't exist on the datatable itself, I need to do the following.

```
 $('[datepicker]').each(function () {
    var selectedDate = $(this).val();
    datePickerList.push(selectedDate);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to find out all `datepickers` in `table` like,

```
table.find('[datepicker]') // get all datepicker in table
     .each(function () {
        var selectedDate = this.value;
     });
```